# Symfony - Manjaro Linux

Tags: symfony, locale, letters, turkish, manjaro

Im using Symfony on Manjaro. And getting this error on default project;

Neither the property "ip" nor one of the methods "ip()", "getip()"/"isip()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profile" in @WebProfiler/Profiler/layout.html.twig at line 71

But i checked Profile file and ip(),getip(),isip() defined as ip,getIp(),isIp().

I think its caused by turkish letters.i was getting similar errors on ubuntu and export LC_ALL=C solves it.
But on manjaro this doesn't work. I tried export lang=en_US.UTF-8 or export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 already. 
Currently lang=tr_TR.UTF-8 , LC_ALL=tr_TR.UTF-8
Any suggestions with that?

Edit:I checked again and __call doesn't exist.Also im not getting any error on prod mode.(app.php)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its about policies of Turkish Republic. Set your clock back 1 hour and try again...